# Android activity produces black screen because of the content

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 2 activities.

ActivityA starts activityB from a button click.

When the button is clicked i create a new dialog and display an image as a kind of cut down loading screen (not bothered with progress bars).

when activityB starts the dialog from ActivityA is killed and i immediately start a new one at the top of oncreate. My oncreate for activityB does quite a few things.

Creates an adview, some text for the main view and creates a GLsurface renderer.

The problem is that when activityB's oncreate is called i get a 4 second black screen between my two dialogs. I would like to try and reduce this as much as i can.

So is there anyway to have the dialog in activity B run immdeiately rather than waiting for the rest of the onCreate to finish doing what it is doing. Will provide code if need be

UPDATE. it is the creation of my glsurface renderer that is causing the black screen for so long. Here is the Activity B code

```
public class ActivityB extends BaseGameActivity
{
/** Hold a reference to our GLSurfaceView */
private MyGLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
public GamePlay GamePlay;
public GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
private AdView adView;
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "******************************";
private Button RotateButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // load screen dialog
     Dialog loader_dialog = new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        loader_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
        loader_dialog.show();
    // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("*****************************").build();
    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    final TextView Score = new TextView(this);
    Score.setText(" 0");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scoreParams = new 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    Score.setLayoutParams(scoreParams);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Fonts/test.ttf");
    Score.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
    Score.setTypeface(tf);
    Score.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FDAA03"));

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View userInterface = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_interface, null);

    GameButton = (Button) userInterface.findViewById(R.id.gamebutton);

    GameButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            //irrelivant game stuff

        }
    });

    // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2)
    {

        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        mGLSurfaceView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this); new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);           
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);          
        // Set the renderer to our demo renderer, defined below.
        mGoogleApiClient = getApiClient();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
                new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        layout.addView(mGLSurfaceView);
        layout.addView(userInterface);
        layout.addView(Score);
        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(this, Score,  mGoogleApiClient),displayMetrics);


        //Set main renderer             
        setContentView(layout); 


    }
    else
    {
        // This is where you could create an OpenGL ES 1.x compatible
        // renderer if you wanted to support both ES 1 and ES 2.
        return;
    }   

}   


@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    // The activity must call the GL surface view's onResume() on activity onResume().
    super.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    // The activity must call the GL surface view's onPause() on activity onPause().
    super.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
}
```

}

Comment: Put the code to display the dialog at the top of `onCrate`. For further help, post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `AsyncTask` for this.

Only prepare the UI elements inside `onCreate` (get references to views you need, show dialog) but move all the heavy lifting tasks to an `AsyncTask`, and update the UI (dismiss dialog, populate views, ...) from there in `onPostExecute` once the loading is done. You could even use the `AsyncTask` to show loading progress if needed ;)

Comment: I agree, you should always use AsyncTask for long running tasks, since it was made for things like this.

Comment: @2Dee thanks for your answer, i have updated my question with the activityB code, and the problem is the creating of the GlsurfaceView, is it possible to move this to an AsyncTask, keeping in mind the different parameters passed to the renderer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a

```
public static Dialog d;
```

in Activity A.
show in activity a 
move to activity B
and aftar all the operation done successfull
you can dismiss that dialog from activity B. like

```
if(A.d.isshowing()){
  A.d.dismiss();
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem..

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesnt seem to work, the dialog still seems to get killed when starting the new task even though it is static and i never dismiss() it